# Sort table according to Date , using Linq query in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, sorting

I just created mvc 4 application. In that application I'm having university table.I want to sort this table data according to Create Date(datetime) column

[image]

this is my Ling query and controller method for sort and list this table

```
    [System.Web.Mvc.Authorize]
    public ActionResult U_Index(string HEI_ID = null)
    {
        try
        {

            var Institutes = from university in db.Institutes
                             where university.HEI_ID == HEI_ID
                             select university;

            return View(db.Institutes.OrderByDescending(i => i.Create_Date).ToList());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return View();
        }
    }
```

but this isn't sorting by create data , Just want know the thing I've missed

Comment: have you tried ordering in the Linq query itself?

Comment: replace 'return View(db.Institutes.OrderByDescending' to 'return View(Institutes.OrderByDescending'

Comment: I think no ,can you show me how can do that

Comment: Added it as an answer

Comment: @mofenko thanks after your approch it doesn't return anything

Comment: This is where a good naming convention can help.  If your local variable `var Institutes` was the standard lowercase `var institutes` it would be obvious that `db.Institutes` does not refer to the same variable.  If you're getting no data, ensure there is matching data in the DB.

Answer (score 2):

In the return statement you are using a property of the db variable instead of the Institutes variable you just defined above.

```
return View(db.Institutes.OrderByDescending(i => i.Create_Date).ToList());
```

change this to use the new variable:

```
return View(Institutes.OrderByDescending(i => i.Create_Date).ToList());
```

**Edit**: Reworded the question to a valid answer.  The details provided a valid answer, but was worded as a question.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: I apologize. I am new to SO and didn't have enough reputation to post a comment. I saw the issue and wanted to convey it to the user. I will be more judicious next time.

Answer (score 0):

Try ordering in the Linq query:

```
var Institutes = from university in db.Institutes
                 where university.HEI_ID == HEI_ID
                 orderby university.Create_Date descending
                 select university;
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of is there's some kind of formatting or culture issue happening with your dates.

Comment: you're correct I've been added  tablesorter plugin ,thats why I cannot sort this ,

but If I can disable tablesorter plugin on document load function this problem can solve